# REIT vs Real Estate - 4 Considerations

Tags: united-states, mortgage, real-estate, california, reit

Assume the following scenario: A person wants to invest $100k in REIT or buying a rental property. (Assume a property management company is used so we don't need to compare the work from each.)

1. What effect (if any) does getting a mortgage have for buying the rental property? Does this increase the long-term value of real-estate compared to REIT?
2. Has someone measured the average capital appreciation of REIT vs owning a home over time? Is one a clear winner?
3. Is there a measurable tax benefit to investing in real-estate? How big a difference should this make?
4. Are there long-term average returns that should be used for owning a rental vs REIT to calculate an expected annual return?

Thanks!

Comment: This is really hard to analyze.  So many different REIT's and the options on rental property are also limitless. I am guessing you are trying to decide which would be a better investment given 100k - REIT or rental property? It almost isn't a way to compare as rental property/investing is its own beast.

Comment: Are you looking to do this with personal funds or IRA/tax deferred funds??

Comment: There is much variation. [This site](http://www.realtytrac.com/news/real-estate-investing/first-quarter-2015-residential-rental-market-report/) shows the variation in rental returns: 2% to 25%.  [This REIT](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=SCHH) is averaging 7.87% over the last three years (but not the -6.07% YTD!).  REITs have the bonus of not requiring any personal management involvement.

Comment: @Lindsey not IRA specifically, just generally.

Comment: Since your question mentions taxes, please specify which country you are asking about. Taxes aren't the same everywhere.

Comment: @Chris USA (california)

Answer (score 4):

I think that this mostly depends on your personality, not the return on investment. Are you willing to get nasty phone calls in the middle of the night about a busted water pipe? Can you weather the lack of income if your rental property goes unoccupied for a year? Are you willing to clean up after a resident trashes the place before moving out?

A REIT removes you from all similar considerations yet provide you with a reasonable income.

I am both a renter and an owner of a REIT.